# TreeView IsChecked внутри ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, treeview

я создал ViewModel для TreeView которая должна читать структуру дерева из XML документа.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Tables>
        <StaticGroups>            
            <StaticGroup  Name="StaticGroup1">                
                    <Table>
                        <TableName>TableName1</TableName>
                        <TableTag>TableTag1</TableTag>
                    </Table>
                    <SubGroup Name="SubGroup">      
                        <Table>
                            <TableName>TableName2</TableName>
                            <TableTag>TableTag2</TableTag>
                        </Table>  
                    </SubGroup>             
                    <SubGroup Name="SubGroup1">     
                        <Table>
                            <TableName>TableName2.1</TableName>
                            <TableTag>TableTag2.1</TableTag>
                        </Table>                 
                    </SubGroup>                                             
            </StaticGroup>
            <StaticGroup Name="StaticGroup2">                
                    <Table>
                        <TableName>TableName3</TableName>
                        <TableTag>TableTag3</TableTag>
                    </Table>                                              
            </StaticGroup>
        </StaticGroups>
        <LoadingConditions>
            <LoadingCondition Name="Loading Condition">
                <Table>
                    <TableName>LoadingTable1</TableName>
                    <TableTag>LoadingTableTag1</TableTag>
                </Table>
            </LoadingCondition>
        </LoadingConditions>
    </Tables>
```

**это классы которые отвечают за XML Deserialization**

```
    static public class Deserialize
    {
        static public NavigationTablesXML NavigationXml()
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader file =
             new System.IO.StreamReader(@"..\..\..\..\NavTables.xml");

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NavigationTablesXML));                    

            return (NavigationTablesXML)serializer.Deserialize(file);    

        }

    }


    #region Navigation Tables
    [XmlRoot("Tables")]
    public class NavigationTablesXML
    {
        public NavigationTablesXML()
        {
            StaticTables = new List<StaticTablesGroup>();
        }

        public List<TablesGroupBase> RootGroups
        {
            get
            {

                List<TablesGroupBase> merged = new List<TablesGroupBase>();
                if (StaticTables != null)
                    merged.AddRange(StaticTables);
                if (LoadingConditions != null)
                    merged.AddRange(LoadingConditions);

                return merged;
            }


        }

        [XmlArray("StaticGroups")]
        [XmlArrayItem("StaticGroup", typeof(StaticTablesGroup))]
        public List<StaticTablesGroup> StaticTables { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("LoadingConditions")]
        [XmlArrayItem("LoadingCondition", typeof(LoadingTablesGroup))]
        public List<LoadingTablesGroup> LoadingConditions { get; set; }

    }
    #endregion Navigation Tables

    #region Groups Static & Loading
    [Serializable]
    public class TablesGroupBase
    {
        public TablesGroupBase()
        {

        }

        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }                 

    }


    public class StaticTablesGroup : TablesGroupBase
    {
        public StaticTablesGroup():base()
        {
            SubGroups = new List<StaticTablesGroup>();
            GroupTables = new List<StaticTable>();
        }

        [XmlElement("SubGroup")]
        public List<StaticTablesGroup> SubGroups { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Table", typeof(StaticTable))]
        public List<StaticTable> GroupTables { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class LoadingTablesGroup : TablesGroupBase
    {
        public LoadingTablesGroup():base()
        {
            SubGroups = new List<LoadingTablesGroup>();
            GroupTables = new List<LoadingTable>();
        }

        [XmlElement("SubGroup")]
        public List<LoadingTablesGroup> SubGroups { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Table", typeof(LoadingTable))]
        public List<LoadingTable> GroupTables { get; set; }
    }
    #endregion Groups Static & Loading

    #region Individual Table
    [Serializable]
    public class TableBase
    {

        [XmlElement("TableName")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("TableTag")]
        public string Tag { get; set; }


    }

    [Serializable]
    public class StaticTable:TableBase
    {        
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class LoadingTable : TableBase
    {
    }


    #endregion Individual Table
```

**моя ViewModel которая должна работать с TreeView**

```
    public class NavigationTablesXMLViewModel:ViewModelBase
    {
        private NavigationTablesXML _tables;
        public NavigationTablesXMLViewModel()
        {
            _tables = Deserialize.NavigationXml();            
        }

        public List<TablesGroupBase> TreeData
        {
            get
            {                    
                return _tables.RootGroups;
            }                   
        }
```

**XAML Treeview**

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TablesVM.TreeData}"  >
                    <TreeView.Resources>
                        <data:SourceConverter x:Key="conv" />                        
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource conv}}" 
                                  DataType="{x:Type data:LoadingTablesGroup}">

                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>

                            </StackPanel>        

                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource conv}}" 
                                  DataType="{x:Type data:StaticTablesGroup}">

                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>

                            </StackPanel>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type data:LoadingTable}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>

                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type data:StaticTable}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>

                            </StackPanel>

                        </DataTemplate>

                    </TreeView.Resources>
                </TreeView>
```

как можно сделать так чтобы isChecked срабатывал внутри ViewModel(NavigationTablesXMLViewModel) и при нажатие на parent node отмечались все children. Я добавил isChecked property в ViewModel(NavigationTablesXMLViewModel) но оно конечно же не срабатывает

Comment: А вы не могли бы уменьшить количество кода? Неужели весь этот код необходим для понимания вопроса?

Comment: @VladD конечно я могу уменьшить количество кода, но тогда, как мне кажется, не будет понятно как работает ViewModel. Я спезиально разделил код чтобы было легче его посмотреть. Основной вопрос в том можно ли при таком ViewModel как у меня получить isChecked event  от TreeView без code behind

Comment: Например, я не уверен, что сериализация вообще имеет отношение к вашей проблеме.

Comment: @VladD Вы абсолютно правы, проблема скорей всего не в serialization. Моя проблема в том как построить мой ViewModel чтобы считать данные с XML, и чтобы имел такую же иерархическую структуру как и TreeView

Comment: Что с этой проблемой? Решилась?

Comment: @VladD Дело в том что мне кажется что ViewModel построена неверно и я начинаю ее переписывать. хочу сделать так чтобы было легче добраться до элементов дерева. Это дерево строится  как навигационное и там достаточно много возможных действий над ним.
 Как ты уже понял структура загружается из XML, а дальше при нажатии на Node нужно получить на какой нажали, его parrent и т. д. Сейчас я решил  построить отдельно Group-ViewModel и Table-ViewModel и они будут объединяться в Navigation-ViewModel.  Как вам кажется лучше выстроить ViewModel?

Comment: @VladD  Другой вопрос в том как осуществить коммуникацию между Child-ViewModel и Main-ViewModel. К примеру, произошло нажатие на TableNode естественно itemSelected event уходит в Table_viewModel а мне нужно его получить как то в Main_ViewModel. нужно осуществлять какой то messaging system?

Comment: Ну, как организовать взаимодействие между двумя классами, это по идее стандартная проблема, которая не относится к MVVM. Либо пусть один класс дёргает публичный метод другого, либо выставляет event, либо получает делегат в конструкторе, это уж как вам кажется удобнее/правильнее.